# Where can I find the One Piece English dub with subs?

Tags: one-piece

Does anyone know where I can find the English dub of *One Piece* with English sub? Sometimes I can't understand what they are saying so I need to look at the text, but I can't find English dub with subtitles, only separately dub and sub.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. Please note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so we will only mention legal/official sites if they exist. Answers/comments that mention questionable sites will be removed without prompt.

Comment: Most official sites (Crunchyroll etc) should have subtitles available for the English dubs.

Answer (score 0):

As of right now it seems that the English Dub of One Piece is not on Crunchyroll and it only has the Sub but this should change eventually since Funimation has merged with it but we have no idea when since Sony doesn't like giving us updates.

So funimation has all the English dub episodes with subtitles available but..... only some are free which means you have to pay for their service to get them. All English Sub episodes are available for free on Crunchyrull and Funiamtion.

Answer (score 0):

VRV. This is a free Crunchyroll service. It's free and legal, but you need to watch ads.

Comment: VRV [is merging with Crunchyroll](https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/technology/vrv-merging-with-crunchyroll-service-to-shut-down-may-3/ar-AA19APbo) and will shut down on May 3rd.